# Rails: session variables return nil after redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, session-variables

I'm building a rails api where

ajax request(front end) sends get request to rails as such:

get request -> login user controller (user#index) -> the screens controller (screen#index) -> send back response to front end.

**Issue:** The login session is lost on redirecting it to screen#index.

Code:

**FRONTEND**
(located at : 127.0.0.1/3000, allowed cors on rails backend)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:6536/user/index", 
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

**BACKEND**

**routes:**

```
 get '/user/index' => "user#index", defaults: {format: 'json'}
 get '/screen', to: 'screen#index', defaults: {format: 'json'}
```

**UserController:**

```
 class UserController < ActionController::Base

   def index
     # check if user exists exists in database
     session[:user_id] = 23 

     Rails.logger.info '----------- registered user'
     Rails.logger.info session['user_id']
     redirect_to '/screen'
   end
 end
```

**ScreenController:**

```
 class ScreenController < ActionController::Base

   def index
     Rails.logger.info '----------- fetching user'
     Rails.logger.info session['user_id']

     user = User.find(session['user_id']) # do something with the user
     render json: { status: 'registered' }, status: :ok
   end
 end
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Started GET "/user/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-04 11:50:24 +0530
 Processing by UserController#index as JSON
 ----------- registered user
 23
 Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:6536/screen
 Completed 302 Found in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 10.5ms)


 Started GET "/screen" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-04 11:50:24 +0530
 Processing by ScreensController#index as JSON
 ----------- fetching user

 User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT   [["LIMIT", 1]]
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

The ScreenController has nil session values. Why is the session being lost between the controller redirection?

If I get the page http://127.0.0.1:6536/user/index in the browser, it runs fine.

**Rails logs on browser search:**

```
 Started GET "/user/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-04 12:26:51 +0530
 Processing by UserController#create as JSON
 ----------- registered user
 23
 Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:6536/screen
 Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


 Started GET "/screen" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-04 12:26:51 +0530
 Processing by ScreenController#index as JSON
 ----------- fetching user
 23
 Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: If you copy/paste your exact code of your app it seems there is a typo error: `get '/screens', to: 'screen#index'` should be `get '/screens', to: 'screens#index'` with "screens" controller plural. Maybe that's why your two outputs are differents (`Processing by ScreensController#index as JSON` not working and `Processing by ScreenController#index as JSON` working)

Comment: sorry that's a typo

Comment: Have you tried doing `session[:user_id]` instead of `session[‘user_id’]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add redirection code and do a conditional rendering in success section of AJAX call

```
function make_ajax_call(url){
      $.ajax({
      url: url, 
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(response) {
         if (response.redirect){
           make_ajax_call(response.redirect); // will make a recursive call
         }
          else
         {
          console.info(response.body);
        }
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not a redirection code. It's just another block of code, that gives out the response. I want both the controllers to execute on the same ajax request

Comment: when you say 
     redirect_to '/screen'
the web server return a 302 asking the browser to make another subsequent request to a new url, 

if you want both the codes to run on one request then you need to call the same logic and then do a render

Comment: Does that mean I put the screen's bit of code in user's controller?

Comment: Yeah add the screen controllers logic or add a extra condition in the Ajax's success function or make it recursive. 

Let me modify the above solution..

Comment: Modified the solution take a look